# Google Add-on Card: How to apply color to header text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

The Google Apps Script guide below implies that header text can be colored.

When I try using some HTML tags (such as `<span color>`), any of them actually worked.

Which tag should I use to implement this?

[image: highlighting-section-header]

**UPDATE**

The following is my code to implement the section header. The `<b>` tag pair works, but any attempts I made to apply color failed.

```
CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .addSection(
    CardService.newCardSection()
    .setHeader('<b>header text</b>')
  )
  .build();
```

Comment: How are you building the AddOn Card? Please share the code you are trying to use.

Comment: @Alessandro I'm building the section as follows:
The `<b>` tag works, but any attempts to apply color fails.


`var section = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader(sectionHeaderStyle('<b>header text</b>'));`

Comment: The .setHeader() function accepts a String parameter. What does sectionHeaderStyle function return? Please update this in your question.

Comment: @Alessandro I added my code. I'm sorry that `sectionHeaderStyle` was added by mistake.
And although `setHeader()` takes a string, it can recognize some HTML tags as well, including `<b>`. Also I tried using `HTML Service` classes, but still I failed to apply color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Google Apps Script Card reference doesn't include much about how to handle the Card design but the Google Workspace Add-ons site points to use the [G Suite Addon Design Kit](https://www.figma.com/community/file/848275628252039675).

Regarding the use of HTML the supported tags only a few. To assing a font color use something like this:

```
CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .addSection(
    CardService.newCardSection()
    .setHeader('<font color="#ea9999">header text</font>')
  )
  .build();
```

References

- [UI style guide for Google Workspace add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/gsuite-style)
- [Text Formatting](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting)

Resources

- [Introducing an easier way to design your G Suite Add-on](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/introducing-easier-way-to-design-your-gsuite-add-on.html)