# How to change font color of name in google add on

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

Is it possible to change the color of the font of the name of add on?

Example, I would like to change the color of "Contacts":

[image: sample add on image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64605671/1595451

Comment: @Rubén that thread is about the cards in the add on. the name of the add on is not part of card, if im not mistaken

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.